# Can i have one row in select from other table than currently referred ?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say i have 2 tables "A" and "B", my query is as follows.

```
Select 
count( a."col_A1") as ACount, 
Sum(a."col_A2") as ASum, 
(Select count(b."col_B1") from B b) as BCount 
From A a
```

I'm not able to execute above statement in Oracle but it works fine in MSSQL.

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY 1` to the end of the query.

```
Select count( a."col_A1") as ACount
,      sum(a."col_A2") as ASum
,      (Select count(b."col_B1") from B b) as BCount 
From A a
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alen Oblak.

Answer (score 2):

It's a valid construct, to include a subquery in an aggregation result, but it looks peculiar to me.

I'd construct it as:

```
select
  a.c_col1,
  a.s_col2,
  b.c_col3
from
  (select count(col1) c_col1,
          sum(col2)   s_col2
   from   table_a) a,
  (select count(col3) c_col3
   from   table_b) b
```